# On macOS how to close (kill) all terminal processes(windows)?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, process, kill

Using macOS sierra, i am searching for a command with which i can close/kill all opened terminal windows (processes). 
Also it should killing all processes opened by this terminals...
Why `pkill Terminal` does not work?

Answer (score 4):

#### Short answer:

```
pkill -a Terminal
```

#### Slightly longer answer:

The above command search all processes which have the name "Terminal" in them and kill them. This will kill the shell process (e.g. `bash`) and any processes in the same process tree (commands run under the control of the shell). It probably won't kill GUI applications since they often [double fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon#5386753). Since these are no longer associated with the `Terminal` process, it's not possible to figure out which ones were originally launched by the terminal.

Also, to find the process without killing it, run:

```
pgrep -a Terminal
```

Comment: Why `pkill Terminal` does not work?

Comment: Sorry, it does. Answer has been edited to correct my mistake

Comment: I have tried pkill -a Terminal - yes it closes all terminals. But when i open terminal again- all previously closed windows open again =(

Comment: I see. This is the best I can think of at the moment: 
`tell application "Terminal"
 close every window
 quit
end tell`
But it prompts you to confirm the closing of each tab. I haven't figured out how to bypass that via script.

Answer (score 0):

How about `cmd+q`? It closes the application and all windows of it. If you can send **keyboard command**.

- It will ask you if you want to terminate all processes before closing all terminals.
- It does not re-open all closed terminals on next launch.

Comment: tried this, but it does not kill processes, that was running in terminals. I have nodejs processes in terminals - terminals closed with cmd+q, but if i run terminal again -`pgrep node` shows this proceses still running

Comment: sorry to hear that :( it worked for me though, will leave answer for other googlers